# How can I achieve overflow central green div-block by other neighbouhrs?

Tags: html, css

better to say I need that central block was visible full, but the others almost on half, I used z-index, used opacity, used overflow, but still can't find the asnwer, here is my fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/Z23du/ I hope you understand clear what I want to do, thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .container div z-index was overwriting the class f2 z-index. By marking a css style as !important you can make sure it doesn't get overwritten.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z23du/6/

Comment: It is crossbrowser. It is part of the CSS spec. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules